# Magento 2.3 - Theme installation error

Tags: magento2.3.3, custom-theme

After move theme folder (app, pub, lib) to root folder then run php bin/magento setup:upgrade getting the following error,

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

> Installing data... SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1062 Duplicate entry '21' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `eav_attribute_set` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`,
>   `sort_order`, `attribute_set_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

After check with eav_attribute_set Duplicate entry 21 is my eav_attribute_set. What i need to do further shall i delete and run again the php bin/magento setup:upgrade?

Screenshot : https://snipboard.io/v1z0f2.jpg

Comment: have you find solution of this problem? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Check your theme files, give proper permission, check log errors.